# Spring Boot: Connect to MSSQL by means of an Active Directory user

Tags: sql-server, spring, spring-boot, active-directory

I like to deploy a Spring Boot application to a K8s cluster and connect to a MSSQL database. The driver definition is:

> spring.datasource.driverClassName=net.sourceforge.jtds.jdbc.Driver

Currently, I connect by means of an user that is implemented by the database itself. Here is the connection string:

> datasourceUrl: jdbc:jtds:sqlserver://server-host/db-name;instance=MSSQL

Now, I want to use an Actice Directory user. Thus, I have updated the credentials. Then, the connection cannot be established anymore. Some research revealed, that adding `domain=domain-name` or `integratedSecurity=true` to the connection string should enable the connection. Unfortunately, both does not work.

Using `domain=domain-name` leads to:

> The login is from an untrusted domain and cannot be used with Windows authentification

Using `integratedSecurity=true` leads to:

> ConfigServletWebServerApplicationContext : Exception encountered during context initialization - cancelling refresh attempt: org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'jdbcConverter' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/data/jdbc/JdbcRepositoriesAutoConfiguration$SpringBootJdbcConfiguration.class]: Unsatisfied dependency expressed through method 'jdbcConverter' parameter 4; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'jdbcDialect' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/data/jdbc/JdbcRepositoriesAutoConfiguration$SpringBootJdbcConfiguration.class]: Bean instantiation via factory method failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [org.springframework.data.relational.core.dialect.Dialect]: Factory method 'jdbcDialect' threw exception; nested exception is org.springframework.jdbc.CannotGetJdbcConnectionException: Failed to obtain JDBC Connection; nested exception is java.sql.SQLException: Login failed for user 'ad-username'

Any ideas on how to establish a connection to the MSSQL database by means of an Active Directory user?

Comment: I don't believe the jtds driver supports AD authentication.  The Microsoft JDBC driver allows AD auth but there are a [number of prerequisites](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/linux/sql-server-linux-active-directory-authentication?view=sql-server-ver15) which may be problematic from a container.

Answer (score 1):

Thank you [Dan Guzman](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3711162/dan-guzman) for your comment.

There is another a way you can establish a connection to the MSSQL database by means of an Active Directory user by adding Active Directory user group as login. It describes how to create a login in SQL Server or SQL Database by using SQL Server Management Studio or Transact-SQL. A login is the identity of the person or process that is connecting to an instance of SQL Server.

Please refer this MS Q&A same thing has discussed over here : https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/questions/131424/how-to-add-active-directory-user-group-as-login-in.html

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/security/authentication-access/create-a-login?view=sql-server-ver15